# PHP system() or shell_exec(): execute another shell

Tags: php, bash, zsh, system, shell-exec

I'm using system() and shell_exec() but it seems that this funcions use /bin/sh always. I want to use another shell when I call this functions: bash or zsh. Is it possible?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is just a symbolic link to your default shell program.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be:

```
<?php
   \system('bash -c "here your command"');
```

or

```
<?php
   \system('zsh -c "here your command"');
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the point? If you use `system` to start another shell script, that shell script itself can decide (via its `#!` line) which shell it is supposed to be processed by. Aside from this, you can always explicitly call the shell. For instance, if you want to take advantage of globbing operators specific to zsh or specific zsh builtins, you can do a

```
# Produce list of files including hidden files. Use
# the zsh-builtin command instead of /usr/bin/echo :
system('zsh -c "echo *(DN)"')
```

Comment: The point is, knowing what default shell it uses, not having to specifically call a different shell and have another quote mess on top of what is already a quote mess!

Comment: `#!` is useless for commands you just want to run directly.

Comment: @redanimalwar : What do you mean by "command being run directly"? If I do a `system("myscript""), and _myscript_ is executable and has a proper #! line, it gets executed.

Comment: What I obviously mean is when you're not run a script, but a simple command directly in the system call. How do you not understand this?

Comment: I guess PHP uses the default shell for the user who executes the PHP script, but It could be that PHP uses just `sh` (edit OP actually said it does) and that actually points to different shells on different systems AFAIK and that is BAD! I would be **very** helpful to just set a shell for PHP to use for all shell calls instead of having to mess around with `system('zsh -c "` this shit.

Comment: I'm not that fluent in PHP, but as far I understand, `system` and `exec` are ill-designed in that they expect as argument a **command**, and this means that the command needs to be **parsed** according to some shell rules. And since the docs don't specify a **syntax** for this command, it is safe to assume that the command will just be handled over to some default shell (Most likely CMD on Windows, sh everywhere else). You **can** bypass this silly interim shell, by using [pcntl_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php), but you have to do the fork manually then.